# span hover inside <a> tag

Tags: html, css

I am using a span inside an `<a>` tag and I would like to change hover color only on the text under `<span>` so it overrides default hover CSS.

```
<div id="box">
     <h4>Title</h4>
     <p><a href="#"><span>Profile</span></a>  |
       <a href="#">Logout</a></p>
   </div>
```

In this example I would need different hover color only on span text. How do i need to define this in CSS ?

I have tried

```
 #box a:hover span{
color: #000;}
```

and

```
 #box span:hover{
color: #000;}
```

both won't work.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook into the `:hover` pseudo-class of the anchor, and then target the `<span>` element:

```
a:hover span {
    color: red;
}
```

Alternatively, you can also style the `:hover` pseudo-class of the span, for example:

```
a span:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Does anyone care to explain the reason behind the downvote here, please?

Comment: No, it does work. You might need to adjust the selector so that it is more specific. Don't forget that CSS is cascading, more specific selectors will overwrite less specific ones.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `span:hover` as part of your selector (or `something:hover span` depending on what you actually want).